# How do I tell Sonar not to store the source code in the database?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am trying two options.

1. One is not to store source code
2. If it is not possible how to delete project from sonar database?

I tried  with "sonar.import Sources=false" but this is not working for sonar version 6.1(deprecated after 4.5 version).
If I delete the project,will source code remain in database?

Answer (score 0):

Storage of source code in database can't be disabled because it's used to display data in webapp.

Source code is indeed dropped from db when deleting a project.

Comment: but when i delete project (UI) and try to create a project with deleted project key and name ,it is showing Analysis is done but in server ,project is not showing

Comment: that's another topic. This thread is about storage of source code. Please open a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but might be helpful for someone:

1. Sonar usually cache the project for performance purpose via squid mechanism, then thru queue mechanism it stores the project data in internal h2 database which can be changed to few supported databases, then you will be having advanced options to manipulate data on database(things like fail-over cases can be achieved), **not that I know of any way of not to store project data in database**.
2. Unless you configure certain user, default user can be **admin** to sonar dashboard with password as **admin**, Login to console and navigate to Administration-> projects->Management, now delete n number of unnecessary projects. Once you do this Sonar dashboard will not be able to show the project again until you re-analyze same project. To make sure this worked,after re-analyzing project click on the project on dashboard and check the version under Activity.

**Additional info:** If you modify the maven project code, first build the project & then do sonar:sonar for latest modifications to be reflected.

I agree with other answer, elaborating in few lines..